# MySql InnO DB cluster node not rejoin automatically to the Cluster

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, innodb, mysql-error-1064, mysql-cluster

I have implemented MySQL InnoDB cluster with 3 nodes.when I stop MySql service on one of the slave node, Cluster change the slave node status to Missing state.
When I start Mysql service on stopped node Cluster not rejoin the node automatically.I need to manually rejoin the node cluster using

```
mysql-js>cluster.rejoinInstance('ic@ic-2:3306');
```

**Status of My Cluster**

```
mysql-js> cluster.status();
{
    "clusterName": "MyCluster", 
    "defaultReplicaSet": {
        "name": "default", 
        "primary": "ic-1:3306", 
        "status": "OK_NO_TOLERANCE", 
        "statusText": "Cluster is NOT tolerant to any failures. 1 member is not active", 
        "topology": {
            "ic-1:3306": {
                "address": "ic-1:3306", 
                "mode": "R/W", 
                "readReplicas": {}, 
                "role": "HA", 
                "status": "ONLINE"
            }, 
            "ic-2:3306": {
                "address": "ic-2:3306", 
                "mode": "R/O", 
                "readReplicas": {}, 
                "role": "HA", 
                "status": "(MISSING)"
            }, 
            "ic-3:3306": {
                "address": "ic-3:3306", 
                "mode": "R/O", 
                "readReplicas": {}, 
                "role": "HA", 
                "status": "ONLINE"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ther is any possibility to rejoin the node to cluster automatically?